# Two functions satisfying a particular condition

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find two *distinct* continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ satisfying

$\vert f(x)-g(y) \vert \leq \vert x-y \vert$

for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have tried various examples like $f(x)=\vert x \vert$, $g(y)=y^2$; $f(x)= \sin x$, $g(y)= \vert y \vert $ and many more.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $x=y$ then you have $|f(x) - g(x)| \leq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, hence $f(x) = g(x)$.

Comment: can we find distinct continuous functions $f$ and $g$ such that $\vert f(x)-g(y) \vert \leq \vert x-y \vert $ if $x \neq y$

Comment: I'll have to check but I don't think so, because $x$ and $y$ can still get arbitrarily close to each other. We're looking for 2 functions such that $|f(x) - g(y)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y| < \varepsilon$, both continuous no less.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary $x$, when $y$ approaches $x$, the difference $|f(x)-g(y)|$ gets squeezed to zero, hence $$\lim_{y\to x}\,g(y)=f(x).$$
For $g$ continuous this implies $g(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Indeed......!!!